# java file will not launch from .desktop file - Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, unity, bash, launcher, java

I have a bin/bash script-

```
 #!/bin/bash

 java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -jar KeeperDesktop.jar
```

inside an executable text file ( keeper-start)

I have created a .desktop file for it as i want to launch it from Unity Launcher

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Keeper
Type=Application
Exec=java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -jar KeeperDesktop.jar
Terminal=false
Icon=/home/dt/keeper/keeper.jpg
Comment=KeeperSecurity Datavault
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Applications
Name[en]=keeper.desktop
```

I have the icon in the Launcher but the app won't start

This is the limit of my knowledge that I have gleaned from other answers on this site
, I am hoping someone can help me finish this process

thanks
David

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is to make sure your .desktop file has executable permissions and that KeeperDesktop.jar is in your home directory.

Comment: I would write `KeeperDesktop.jar` in an absolute path: `/path/to/KeeperDesktop.jar`

Comment: Pandya - java file java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -jar KeeperDesktop.jar does not run from terminal, says 'unable to access  jarfile KeeperDesktop.jar'

Comment: saiarcot895 - my .desktop file (keeper.desktop) is stored in /usr/share/applications directory permissions say 'owner - root' and permissions are not executable (option greyed out) 'I cannot change permissions as I am not the owner' . KeeperDesktop.jar is in /Home/dt/keeper folder

Comment: SOLVED - chaos- your suggestion was correct, I changed the path to an absolute one and it works, thank you so much man, regards, David

Answer (score 0):

Answer taken from comments

**Chaos**

> I would write `KeeperDesktop.jar` in an absolute path:
>   `/path/to/KeeperDesktop.jar`

**DaveyT**

> SOLVED - chaos- your suggestion was correct, I changed the path to an
>   absolute one and it works …

Comment: @JacobVlijm changed =)